# When i pass the parameter as the props my function works but when i set the number manually the item cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-context

When i call a function and pass in id as props the function gets the item. But when i set the id manually it doesnt find the item.

```
This works
     <div className="img-container p-5"
                    onClick={() => value.handleDetail(this.props.id)}>
                   getItem = id => {
        const product = this.state.products.find(item => item.id === id);

        return product;
      };
 This doesnt
  <div className="img-container p-5"
                    onClick={() =>
 let id = 1 value.handleDetail(this.props.id)}>


    getItem = id => {
    const product = this.state.products.find(item => item.id === id);
    return product;
  };
      handleDetail = id => {
        console.log('pikachu');
        const product = this.getItem(id);
        console.log(product);
        this.setState(() => {
          return { detailProduct: product };
        });
      };
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Yes my computer just died one sec

Comment: can you explain this `onClick={() => value.handleDetail(thiswid)}>` look at the parameter you are passing for the `handleDetail` and what is `value.handleDetail`? what does `value` refer to?

Comment: It is reffering to context api file in which i have the function in

Comment: I just updated that was rushing trying to find charger

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is typeof id coming in props and manually setting will be different.
In your code `const product = this.state.products.find(item => item.id === id);` you are comparing value as well as type by using `===`. ie; `item.id === id`

so, when you are setting let id = 1, typeof id is `number` whereas typeof `this.props.id` maybe different, because of which, nothing found.

Comment: Yes but I converted the string into a number which is the same as the prop and still get the same issue

Comment: i compared the two values with === and it returns true

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the state of Products in getItem() was not set yet so what I did was set a timeout in my component did mount and everything works fine now.